# Swift 4 Countdown Timer NowDate - Date

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to make a countdown timer for June 2, 2018. How can I do that. When the user opens the application, it should continue where it left off.

I resolved with this code. Someone else is looking for the same code. I saw somebody's help over Stack Overflow and I finished it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var ayLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gunLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var saatLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dakikaLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var saniyeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secimGunu: UILabel!

let formatter = DateFormatter()
let userCleander = Calendar.current;
let requestedComponent : Set<Calendar.Component> = [
    Calendar.Component.month,
    Calendar.Component.day,
    Calendar.Component.hour,
    Calendar.Component.minute,
    Calendar.Component.second
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timePrinter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    timer.fire()

}

func timeCalculator(dateFormat: String, endTime: String, startTime: Date = Date()) -> DateComponents {
    formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    let _startTime = startTime
    let _endTime = formatter.date(from: endTime)

    let timeDifference = userCleander.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: _startTime, to: _endTime!)
    return timeDifference
}

@objc func timePrinter() -> Void {
   let time = timeCalculator(dateFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a", endTime: "02/06/2018 00:00:00 a")
    ayLabel.text = "\(time.month!)"
    gunLabel.text = "\(time.day!)"
    saatLabel.text = "\(time.hour!)"
    dakikaLabel.text = "\(time.minute!)"
    saniyeLabel.text = "\(time.second!)"

}
```

Comment: From the question, it is not clear what you actually ask for. Are you asking how to make an app? That's a little too broad. Or how to create a Timer object firing at a specific date?

Comment: You mean how to display how many days are left until the World Cup

Comment: @the4kman No need to use a timer

Comment: There will be an election on June 2, 2018. So I need a countdown timer @Mirek

Comment: @UmutCanAlparslan if you just need the number of days you can use a notification for day change to update it. If you want also to display hours, minutes and seconds you would need a repeating timer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Since the question is very broad, the easiest solution is to use one of the many web services to display the countdown and save it as a shortcut to your home page (Share -> Add to Home Screen) in Safari. Like this one:

https://www.timeanddate.com/countdown/generic?iso=20180602T02&p0=136&font=cursive

2. If you really want an app for whatever reason, the easiest option would be to have a single view app to open the URL above in a web view.
3. If you absolutely need to write your own native app. Then you will need to create a single view app in Xcode and with a label in its view and a timer in its ViewController fired every second (or whatever time period you want). The events fired by the timer would decrement the label (or however you want to present the remaining time). The app will also need to handle resume (likely by registering to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`) to make sure the remaining time gets updated when resuming from the background.